# Response with the parent class in SPRING REST

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have implemented a REST API with SPRING REST using Jackson (specifying in the pom.xml with the package org.codehaus.jackson - jackson-mapper-asl - 1.9.13). In the controller I have:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="id", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Parent findById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
       Child child = new Child();
       child.setId(id);
       child.setName("test");
       return child;
    }
}
```

For example in the Parent we could have:

```
public class Parent {
    int id;

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And the child:

```
public class Child extend Parent {
    String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My problem is that I'd want the response to be only with the parent class and not with the child class (because now the response has the structure of the child).

Comment: No idea what the question is. Your child doesn't extend Parent. Check out interfaces.

Comment: Sorry. It was a mistake. The child extend the parent.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that would work for you is the following:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
public class Parent {

    @JsonProperty
    int id;

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I have to admit that this solution is not terribly elegant since you need to add the `@JsonProperty` annotation to every field in the Parent class, but does have the benefit that no modifications are needed to any of it's subclasses

All the annotations that are present in the jackson library can be found [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations).

The javadoc for `@JsonAutoDetect`can be found [here](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.3.0/)